# How to make selection tool with 3 variables which depend on each other (ModelBuilder)?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arctoolbox

I try to create model to selection feature by attribute with 3 variables which depend on each other but i don't know how.
for example:
variables: kat_1, kat_2, kat_3
Kat_1{ gastronomy, education, sport, religion} 
Kat_2{bar,restaurant, kindergarten, elementary school, middle school, high school, church, cemetery, playground, pool, tennis}
 Kat_3{names}

how to create some filtr which works that when I choose gastronomy from kat_1 then it only allow me to choose bar or restaurant from kat_2?

Comment: You should be able to do this using tool validation and a little Python. I think there is an example in the online help which I'll try to locate later if you have not already.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this using **tool validation** is described in this **[10.1 Help Page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000002v000000)** which should apply equally to 10.0.